# MongoDB C# driver, query by an array element using regex

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am using MongoDB C# driver **version 2.2**. My collection contains "Parent" objects. Each parent object has an array of children objects. Each child has name value:

```
"parent": {
    "children":[
        { "name": "Bob", "age": 10},
        { "name": "Alice", "age": 7},
        { "name": "Tobias", "age": 11}
    ]
}
```

I need to translate the following code into C# statements / LINQ syntax:

```
db.getCollection('Parents').find({'parent.children': { $elemMatch: { 'name': { $regex: '.*ob.*', $options: 'im' } }}})
```

I have found there are methods like

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
builder.Regex("parent.children.name", new BsonRegularExpression(".*ob.*")); //does not work with array
```

and

```
builder.AnyEq("parent.children.name", "ob"); //without regex
```

But I cannot understand how to combine them. Please advise.

**UPDATE:**

I am using the following for now, please correct me if you know a reason why it should not work correctly:

```
builder.AnyEq("parent.children.name", new BsonRegularExpression(".*ob.*"))
```

Comment: Your final query looks fine to me, btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the following for now:

```
builder.AnyEq("parent.children.name", new BsonRegularExpression(".*ob.*"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't test C# on this machine. Let me know if this doesn't work:

```
var filter = Builders<People>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Parent.Children, x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Name, "regex"));
var res = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Here's a trick you might like btw:

```
// Take your inputted `find` query string:
string bsonQuery = "{'parent.children': { $elemMatch: { 'name': { $regex: '.*ob.*', $options: 'im' } }}}";

// Use it as the filter!
var filter = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(bsonQuery);

// Results:
var result = col.FindSync (filter).ToList();
```

Comment: In your example you use classes (strongly-typed). All I have is a dotted notation of the "path". Can you please improve your example?

Comment: @Antipod Look up COPOs. They'll make your life a lot easier when querying using C#

Comment: Thank you for the update. I am almost sure the provided update will work. The issue is: it is a string and I do not want to construct strings, we have the methods in the driver which we can use and the driver will construct queries for us, after all: ) Speaking about POCOs, I 100% agree with you, but I have a requirement - JSON does not have a defined structure, it is dynamic.

Comment: Whilst JSON is dynamic, your first-class objects in C# are not. So writing COPOs on a use-by-use basis even if the data may change makes sense for the C# code operating on them.

Comment: thank you for your opinion. Unfortunately, POCO is an off-topic in my question, sorry for that :) BTW, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your current expression (`builder.AnyEq("parent.children.name", new BsonRegularExpression(".*ob.*")`) on a database at home and I don't believe it behaves in the way you intend.

[Although the c# documentation doesn't explicitly state this](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_Regex.htm), mongoDB supports the Regex filter on an array field. I have tested the below expression in C# and have correct results for the Regex despite the field being an array.

```
builder.Regex(MONGO_FIELD_NAME, new BsonRegularExpression("SOME REGEX"));
```

In addition, I've tested Regex on the toy example in the [online mongo webshell for query arrays] (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/). Querying for `db.inventory.find({tags : {$regex : "^bl"}}` will return results with "blank" or "blue" despite the "tag" field being an array.