# How to search for a string in an array of objects in MongoDB with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, mongodb, string-search

I have the following record in my MongoDB. I want to search for a string in the "monday" fields. I want to search the "learningexperience" field to return any documents that matches a certain word in that field.

Not sure how to do it using MongoDB/C#. Any help would be fantastic.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ee623844bd6b042809d492"),
    "title" : "Zebra Room (2017-10-30)",
    "weekcommencing" : "2017-10-30", 
    "monday" : [ 
        {
            "categoryid" : "59ee610244bd6b042809d48d",
            "category" : "Culture & Community",
            "learningexperience" : "Dress up to reflect where i am from. Children are asked to dress in the national uniform of their origins."
        }, 
        {
            "categoryid" : "59edca4344bd6d1e200c3c32",
            "category" : "Literacy & Numeracy",
            "learningexperience" : "Today the children will be focusing on simple additions. For those more advance we will also have subtractions in place."
        }
]
}
```

Comment: [MongoDB C# driver, query by an array element using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38699179/2313887)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search it with something like %keyword%. You may try this

```
db.tablename.find({"monday.learningexperience": /.*keyword.*/})
```

For C# you may try this filter (mongodb c# driver 2.0 or higher )

```
Builders<tablename>.Filter.Regex("monday.learningexperience", new BsonRegularExpression("keyword", "i"));
```